# SQL Server Alter Stored Procedure without validating script

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, alter

I have a stored procedure that connects to 2 databases. This stored procedure will be used in one of the SSRS reports (SSRS has permission for both databases).

But I only have access to the database where the stored procedure reside.

When I try to alter the stored procedure, I get an error that I don't have permission for the 2nd database.

Is there any way to alter the stored procedure without validating the script inside it?

P.S. dynamic SQL is not acceptable where I work

```
ALTER PROCEDURE DB1.[DB1].[SP1]
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT *
    FROM Server2.DB2.dbo.Table2 AS T2
    INNER JOIN DB1.dbo.Table1 AS T1 ON T1.ID = T2.ID 
END
```

Error

> Msg 18456, Level 14, State 1, Line 8
>   Login failed for user 'CompanyName\MyUserID'

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to prevent SQL Server from Validating the SQL in a stored procedure during CREATE / ALTER](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7558184/is-there-a-way-to-prevent-sql-server-from-validating-the-sql-in-a-stored-procedu)

Comment: @Ken, that answer says to use dynamic SQL, while OP's question here indicates they need a solution that doesn't use dynamic SQL.

Comment: see if something here could help:  https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/81566/create-alter-stored-procedure-without-compiling

Comment: @RichardII: The linked duplicate asks the same question, and does not specify with or without dynamic SQL. The fact that the accepted answer uses dynamic SQL doesn't change the question. It's also telling that the question did not get alternative solutions, and that the link you provided says it's not possible otherwise.

Comment: Not possible: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/148047/deferred-name-resolution-for-linked-servers

Comment: Can I update records manually in sys.sql_modules table?

Comment: No, you can't...

Comment: @Alex just found this https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/73557/script-that-alters-all-stored-procedure-on-the-database

Comment: The link above has nothing to do with updating sys.sql_modules table.

Comment: @Alex I think the table I need is sys.Procedures not sys.sql_modules

Comment: You better invest your efforts into getting access to the other DB, as you cannot (and should not) update system DBs directly.

Comment: @Alex when you say "should not", that means it is possible.. even if in my case this is not the best way to update SP, but this could help other people in their case to update SP from system table is the only way.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189426/discussion-between-alex-and-asmgx).

Comment: @KenWhite - So he can't ask a question because there's a similar question that has an answer that the OP **can't use**? Just goes to show how LAME these close votes are. I guess if I ask about the Meaning of Life, I'll get a close vote because there's a question about 6 times 7?

Comment: @HannoverFist: I didn't say anyone couldn't ask whatever they like. I said there was an existing duplicate. If you disagree, don't vote to close as a duplicate.